# How is ProcessInstanceInfo related to SessionInfo in jBPM5?

Tags: jbpm

I need to export some process data from my jBPM database, and I should be able to select some specific process instances to export, but I cannot find the relationship between ProcessInstanceInfo and SessionInfo.

Given a list of process instance ids, how can I export all information related to those process instance ids?

I can find the following relationships:

ProcessInstanceInfo via instanceid
EventTypes via instanceid
WorkItemInfo via processinstanceid

**UPDATE:**

Suppose I have 5 task nodes in my process, A B C D E, A & B are executed on Public network, and C, D & E are executed on Private network, so I have to export process instances whose A & B task nodes are completed on Public to Private so that tasks on Private network can be completed and process instances can be continued.

Tasks in one process are isolated, so I have to 'export' process instances from one to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you mean with export? 
ProcessInstanceInfo and SessionInfo are internal tables for the engine to work, you should not be using those tables.

Cheers

Comment: Tasks in one process are isolated, so I have to 'export' process instances from one to another. Please see the updated part in the subject.

Comment: I found that I don't need SessionInfo to migrate process and task data. Now I load the session instead. But I encountered another problem, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913937/no-new-task-created-after-restart.